# How can I implement SCSS into Hydrogen V2

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-hydrogen

I'm currently working on a shopify project using Hydrogen V2. Would anyone know how to implement scss into the project? I keep receiving this error:

No loader is configured for ".scss" files: app/components/Header/styles.scss

I would rather not use Tailwind and on the documentation Tailwind is the only option to style. The only thing I've found online is to npm install sass sass-loader css-loader style-loader --save-dev and then from there go onto the remix.config.js file and add this:

```
  middleware: {
compile: {
  // Add SCSS support
  'text/scss': {
    module: 'sass',
    options: {
      sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['./src'],
      },
    },
  },
},
```